# Why does the desktop icon differ from the explorer icon?

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

For some reason, a very old version of my icon keeps showing up when my application is dropped on the desktop. In the windows explorer (in all zooming levels) the icons is correctly the assembly icon. I specified the correct item in both XAML Window.Icon and in the project settings. 
I have deleted the old version of my icon from all folders I can think of, but it still shows up. Also while drag and dropping, the wrong icon is shown. (in the slightly transparent preview window)

I tried cleaning and rebuilding, I tried deleting the obj folder manually...
The original, wrong icon was 16x16. I have built the new version as 32x32, because on the desktop 16x16 is too small. 
According to the msdn docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx), each .ico file is supposed to incorporate all smaller sizes anyway.
I also checked that I changed the icon for both debug and release configuration.

Thanks for any ideas! :)

Comment: Have you tried installing it on a different machine or on a VM?

Comment: Have you checked that all of the sizes inside the .ico file are the same image? An .ico file contains multiple sizes, but each are independent, meaning the 16x16 can look completely different from the 32x32.

Comment: @wheaties: Thanks for the idea. I just tried it on a pretty new laptop and the icon shows up correctly. I guess I'll try to restart my computer, as stupid as that sounds. @JoeL: how do I check that? I created the .ico in Photoshop with a plugin. I dont see any other images either with VS or with PS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be a problem with the IconCache? Try deleting `%localappdata%\IconCache.db` and restarting Explorer.exe.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! This seems like an odd problem to have. Do you have more info on the icon cache? I didn't find anything specific on msdn. For example: How it gets created, and when it normally refreshes.

Comment: All I know is that on every Windows machine I've ever had, it gets corrupted, so this is a procedure I'm very familiar with. IIRC TweakUI had an option to do this on the user's behalf, so it's a problem that MS are aware of. I'm surprised it persists.

Comment: I added another icon just to check, and this time there was no iconcache.db to delete. But restarting the explorer helped anyway. So maybe not even a problem of the cache.

Comment: Yep, icon handling in Windows is a bit borked. The caching is a good thing (especially if your desktop is as crowded as mine), but it's definitely not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Visual Studio properties window for the EXE's project -- you can specify the icon that's written into the EXE at compile time. This is separate from the icon that's assigned to the XAML window at run time.

Comment: 1. I did that already, if you mean the "Icon and manifest" setting specified in the Application tab. 2. In the floating properties window are only two choices available: "project file" and "project folder". No icon. I'm using VS2010. 3. I changed the "build action" in the Icon property to "compile", but that didn't fix it.